# Define the linear transformation T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}4&-5\\-3&-2\\23&-23\end{bmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix}-37\\-1\\-184\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Define the linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 | as \ T(x) = A(x)|$ Find a vector $x$ whose image under $T$ is $b$

I'm unsure of how exactly to do this. Should I start by putting it in RREF?

I tried putting it in RREF and got stuck here

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3\\0&1&5\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $[-3, 5]^T$. Just consider $A[x,y]^T = b$.

Comment: @StevenHarding The purpose of Math.StackExchange is to instruct and inform. Your answer does neither.

Comment: That is why I left a comment, not an answer. It is simply a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Take the augmented matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -5 & -37\\
-3 & -2 & -1 \\
23 & -23 & -184 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and put it in RREF. This will allow you to read off a solution.

Edit: Now that you have the RREF, you can read off the solutions as follows:

Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ be a solution to the equation $Tx = b$. The first row of the matrix tells you that $$x_1 + 0x_2 = -3.$$ So $x_1 = -3$.

The second row of the matrix tells you that $$0x_1 + x_2 = 5.$$ So $x_2 = 5$.

Comment: Check out my updated OP Ken. I got stuck trying to put it in RREF. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is hard to say where the mistake occured. Likely it is a small computational error along the way. If you can show me your intermediary steps then I would be able to help more.

Comment: Updated with the correct RREF form. How now do I obtain the solutions?

Comment: Nvm, it was -3, 5 haha Im an idiot

Comment: It happens to us all. Glad you figured it out!